# WITH is required between MERGE and MATCH (line 4, column 1 (offset: 63))

Tags: neo4j, nosql, graph-databases

I am trying to use CYPHER to create a simple graph on NEO4J.

Below is the query:

```
MERGE (nut:asset{name:'nut'})
MERGE (bolt:asset{name:'bolt'})

MATCH (nut:asset)
WITH nut,bolt
MERGE (nut:asset)-[:hasPart]->(washer:asset{name:'washer',domain:'tool'})
```

Its throws me an error

```
WITH is required between MERGE and MATCH (line 4, column 1 (offset: 63))
"MATCH (nut:asset)"
 ^
```

When I try to change my query to

```
MERGE (nut:asset{name:'nut'})
MERGE (bolt:asset{name:'bolt'})

MERGE (nut:asset)-[:hasPart]->(washer:asset{name:'washer',domain:'tool'})
```

Its says

```
Can't create node `nut` with labels or properties here. The variable is already declared in this context
```

How to use the MERGE statement in this context. I have used the tutorial from Neo4j [link](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) to construct my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error was caused because after creating two nodes, you directly used `MATCH`. The query is continuous but you broke it into parts using `MATCH` with a label. In order to maintain continuation you've to use `WITH`.

The second error was caused because you are using the same variable `nut` twice.

Using [`WITH`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/) you can reduce the cardinality and time taken by the query.

The first query can be written like this:

```
MERGE (nut:asset{name:'nut'}) 
with nut
MERGE (bolt:asset{name:'bolt'}) 
with nut,bolt
MERGE (nut)-[:hasPart]->(washer:asset{name:'washer',domain:'tool'})
```

and the second one:

```
MERGE (nut:asset{name:'nut'})
MERGE (bolt:asset{name:'bolt'})

MERGE (nut)-[:hasPart]->(washer:asset{name:'washer',domain:'tool'})
```